# How can I add four spaces before each lines of programs code in terminal

Tags: bash, text-processing

I usually go to stackexchange when I face programming terminal and I spend most of time trying to append four spaces before my pasted programming code.

Is there any faster way to do it from a terminal?
What would you do?

Comment: You can just highlight the code and click the `{ }` button on the S.E. editor interface to do the indent.

Comment: @goldilocks O, wow, I never knew that :o

Comment: Ctrl-K does this from the keyboard. Select the region you want to format as code, then type this keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use sed,

```
sed 's/^/    /' file
```

This appends four spaces before each line. Add an inline edit option `-i`  to save the changes to the specified file.

```
sed -i 's/^/    /' file
```

Through awk,

```
awk '{sub(/^/, "    ", $0)}1' file
```

OR

```
awk '{print "    "$0}' file
```

Comment: I think the first `sed` command would be more than sufficient. Here, you typically don't want `-i` and `awk` seems overly complicated. Maybe add that `^` matches the beginning of the line.